# Why does the letter Hei stands for Shechinah

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, commentaries, aleph-bet-letters, thought

Why is it the letter ה which represents or is connected with the Shechinah? What is the explanation behind this idea?

Comment: How do you know that such a connection exists?

Comment: @DoubleAA I read this in many articles which presented different examples. One of them was a explanation from the chabad website that the final letter ה in יהוה associates with malchut, the sefira of the Shechinah. From kabbalah online (also from the chabad website): teshuva [repentance] is "teshuv-H": the letter that represents the Shechinah.

Comment: @DoubleAA R. Bachye explains, because 'Hey' (the last letter in G-d's Holy Name) represents the Shechinah.

Comment: A suffix hei is also the usual way to make a word feminine. But in the case of sheim havayah, the final hei is part of the root, which is \הוה\, to exist. As for the question, I am not competent to discuss most things -- but with regard to Qabbalah, I know enough to be aware of my ignorance.